# Any spells that would allow a mage to breathe while buried alive?

Tags: spells, world-of-darkness, mage-the-ascension, breathing

If a mage were buried alive for whatever reason - whether deliberate as some part of a gambit of sorts or not so deliberately via accident or attack - does there exist any specific magic or uses of magic, that would allow them to survive buried and avoid what should be a rapid suffocation for an extended period of time?

I have a suspicion some skill with the Forces sphere with it's manipulation of elements might have potential on this front, but as a whole I'm not entirely certain.

Any disciplines and potential ways would do good for an answer to this question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simplest way is through Life 3 (Alter Self), changing the way the mage's lungs take in air, or through Matter 2, turning the carbon dioxide exhaled back into oxygen.

Answer (score 10):

Some ways to survive to being buried alive could imply some effects of (including the examples in [@Jadasc's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/145572/any-spells-that-would-allow-a-mage-to-breathe-while-buried-alive/145575#145575))

- Time 3 / Life 3 to enter in state of suspension (How do you do that,
  page 113).
- Time 3 / Correspondence 4: Bind a location (the coffin) into stasis
  (ibid.).
- Correspondence 3: Teleport outside the burial site (How do you do that,
  page 77).
- Correspondence 4: Create some kind of stable portal to take inside
  fresh air (How do you do that, page 79).
- Life 3: Change your body to be able to breath CO2.
- Life 2: Slow down your metabolism to breath only once every several minutes.
- Matter 2: Transform CO2 into breathable oxygen.

Comment: While this answer lists some interesting examples, it seems to be referring to another answer above. You could make this answer better by making it stand on its own and include those examples too.

Comment: @DannyCuppen I have included Jadasc examples to this asnwer.